# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"} when clicking the link to root_path - user is signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and am currently on chapter 9 - I am using Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3p362

There is only one test that is not passing:

```
1) Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

However, if I a user is signed in, he cannot visit any of the static pages! Attempting to do so results in the same error:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

There are no filters on the static_pages controller.

Here is the session_helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

And here is the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user, only:[:edit, :update]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to The New Outfit Project!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user 
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end


    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

Routes.rb

```
Heart::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  get "static_pages/home"

  get "static_pages/help"

  get "static_pages/terms"

  get "static_pages/howitworks"

  get "static_pages/contact"

  get "static_pages/privacy"

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/terms', to: 'static_pages#terms'
  match '/privacy', to: 'static_pages#privacy'
  match '/howitworks', to: 'static_pages#howitworks'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

  resources :outfits


  resources :users

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

I am not sure what I have done to cause this behavior.

Thanks

Sam

Editing -

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-25 08:36:09 -0500
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remember_token` = 'BfOZrKGkLDUxjjj6W4MdPw' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2220788467796044097_70169256016500'
```

Comment: Where is the error coming from?

Comment: It comes in two different ways: when i run the test and when i am on the browser, signed in as user and try to click on any of the static pages links.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace when clicking on the link?

Comment: Edited to add the stacktrace.

Comment: What is on the line generating the error? app/views/layouts/application.html.erb line 35

Comment: Line 35 of the application.html.rb: ` <li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path  %></li>`

Comment: Ugh! I found the issue, thanks to your help with looking at the right line of code. Feeling pretty dumb right now - it should be user_path(current_user) not just user_path.

Comment: I've done that a hundred times :)

Comment: @Beerlington - would you like to answer it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from line 35 of your application layout. Your user_path helper method requires a user object to be passed to it so it can grab the ID and create the show route.